# How to loop on startswith method

Tags: python, list, loops, startswith

I need to check if the first word typed is in my list or not

```
name = input("type your name: ")
    
if name.startswith("Tim") or name.startswith("Anna") or name.startswith("Noah") or name.startswith("Justin"):
        print('correct')
else:
     print('false')
```

I need to write it in better way like :

```
myList = ['Tim', 'Anna', 'Noah', 'Justin']
name = input("type your name: ") 
if name.startswith(*any name in my list*):
    print('correct')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **list comprehension** and **any** keyword :

```
myList = ['Tim', 'Anna', 'Noah', 'Justin']
name = input("type your name: ")
if any([name.startswith(item) for item in myList]):
    print('correct')
else:
    print('false')
```

The `if` block can quite literally be interpreted as :
if `name` starts with any of the items in `myList`, then print 'correct'

Comment: You don't want the square brackets here, as a listcomp forces all of the tests to occur before checking if any succeeded, producing a pointless `list`; `any` and `all` should basically always be used with iterators to allow short-circuiting, e.g. with a generator expression, `any(name.startswith(item) for item in myList)` or with `map`, `any(map(name.startswith, myList))`.

Answer (score 1):

[`startswith` already supports this natively, just pass it a `tuple` as the `prefix` argument, rather than a single `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
if name.startswith(("Tim", "Anna", "Noah", "Justin")):
```

It's true if it starts with any of the elements of the `tuple`, and if the `tuple` is of literals as in this case, it's generated and cached at compile time, so the performance is ridiculously good. Under the hood, it's just looping one by one and short-circuiting if it gets a hit, but you don't have to write the loop yourself.